# Trigger page reload after changes to model instance in DjangoCMS' admin panel

Tags: django-cms

DjangoCMS has an admin panel which allows editing of model data without leaving the web page.

Some changes to models, however, require the current web page to be updated and re-retrieved from the server. DjangoCMS does this, for example, in the pages admin page. Certain changes trigger a page reload.

**How can I trigger such a page reload in my apps's `admin.py` if certain changes are made?** Specifically, I need to update the page after some bulk actions which change selected model instances in one go (like the standard `Delete selected items` action).

**Example:**

I have a blog app which uses a DjangoCMS apphook to show a page with a list of blogposts. I navigate to this page and use the admin panel of the post model to, say, publish 5 blog posts using an admin action.

*Current behavior:* The posts are marked published but do not appear on the blog list page until I manually request a page reload.

*Desired behavior:* The mark published action should trigger an automatic page reload after closing the admin panel (if at all possible only if a page is shown that belongs the blog app).

*Potential solution:* DjangoCMS itself has a hook where my ModelAdmin can register that the page will need to be reloaded after the admin panel closes.

Comment: Hello Fabian, you want the CMS to reload the current page if you edit an object through the admin left sidebar? Can you maybe provide a screencast of the actions taken?

Comment: Thanks @Paulo for looking into this. Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Sorry, I do not have a screencast but I added a use case example to the question.